# QueryFailedError upon renaming primary key with TypeORM

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm building a web app for managing surveys with `NestJS` and `TypeORM`.

I use the following two entities with a `@OneToMany` relation (one survey can have many sections):

`survey.entity.ts` :

```
import { Column, Entity, OneToMany, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { SurveySection } from './surveysection.entity';

@Entity()
export class Survey {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(
    'SurveySection',
    (survey_section: SurveySection) => survey_section.survey,
    {
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    },
  )
  sections: Array<SurveySection>;
}
```

and `surveysection.entity.ts` :

```
import { Column, Entity, JoinColumn, ManyToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { Survey } from './survey.entity';

@Entity()
export class SurveySection {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  survey_section_ID: number;

  @Column()
  position: number;

  @ManyToOne('Survey', (survey: Survey) => survey.sections)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'survey_id' })
  survey: Survey;
}
```

This code runs fine.

---

But when I rename `survey_section_ID` in `surveysection.entity.ts` to anything other than "survey_section_ID" and have `synchronize: true` in my `ormconfig.json` I get an error:

```
QueryFailedError: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

When I try renaming `survey_section_ID` to "survey_section_id" (all lowercase), I even get:

```
QueryFailedError: Duplicate column name 'survey_section_id'
```

#### My question is:

Where does the code above rely on the `PrimaryGeneratedColumn` in `surveysection.entity.ts` being named "survey_section_ID" and only that?

---

### Edit:

After deleting `dist` directory from app and readding the exact same entities everything worked.

Comment: read about [`JoinConlumn` here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/7eb032705912cbf4ee340ed9e49970d0f6e23714/docs/relations.md#joincolumn-options)

Comment: Thanks for the resource. Still struggling on this one. Read the docs and played around with the code more. When I remove the `@JoinColumn()` in `surveysection.entity.ts` and rename the `PrimaryGeneratedColumn` it throws `QueryFailedError: You can't delete all columns with ALTER TABLE; use DROP TABLE instead`. 
I then have to manually drop table `survey_section` and reverse renaming of `PrimaryColumn` in order to connect to database again. For some reason the very same setup works perfectly on a table `section_question`  with no `QueryFailedError` whatsoever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

After trying out a lot of things, I noticed that for some reason 3 columns of `survey_section` would keep on being recreated by `TypeORM` even when not included in the code anymore. 
When deleting `surveysection.entity.ts` entirely from the project and dropping table `survey_section` in the database, after restarting the app table `survey_section` would still appear in the database again with said 3 columns.
`ormlogs.log` showed that it removed and readded said 3 columns to table `survey_section`.
`ormconfig.json` had `"synchronize": true` the whole time.

After deleting the whole `dist` directory from the project and readding `surveysection.entity.ts` the exact same sample code in question worked.

One of the 3 columns was `survey_section_ID`. If in fact those 3 columns had always been added behind the scenes, then it would have made sense that no other auto generated column would be addable to the table and that a column named `survey_section_id` would make for a duplicate name.

I don't know how to reproduce this or if I just missed something, but I'll leave this as an answer in case anyone is also experiencing this.